# ASP.NET builds success but showing "Syntax Error" on web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET project which is started by an other team, and I'm currently working on it.

My problem is, I'm specially doing syntax errors and trying to compile project.
Project compiles without any errors. But error is there.

When I try to open the web page it shows me the error like :

[image]

How can I prevent build if there is an error?

Comment: Have you see that in your image it says gext; instead of get? It's extraordinarily surprising that you don't get compiling errors

Comment: @Mayhem: While there's definitely a syntax error there, App_Code directory files get compiled as-needed at runtime, rather than at build time which is why fobus wasn't getting syntax errors when compiling the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any .cs file located in *~/App_Code/* will be dynamically compiled when the application runs.

So in Visual Studio, we can build the same class twice by adding it to App_Code and setting the Build Action to Compile.

or you can avoid *app_code* folder

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

`public string facilityOpeningHours{get;set;}`

You must get the compile time error as the syntax is wrong for initialising the getter & setter for facilityOpeningHours property